# Does syn-dihydroxylation form racemic mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, hydrocarbons, optical-properties, stereoselectivity

I have been asked to determine the nature of the product for the following reaction:

[image: Oxidation reaction]

And as I recognized this reaction to be a case of *syn-dihydroxylation*, my obvious response was that the product formed will be *meso*.

But, in the solution to the problem, it says it makes a racemic mixture.

[image: Oxidation reaction with products]

Shouldn't both the $\ce{-OH}$ be on the same side and form a *meso*-compound? And what does the $(sym)$ stand for?

Comment: The very fact that 'syn' has been written as 'sym' should've heightened your suspicions regarding this answer, which is blatantly wrong. Cold KMnO4 will produce a meso compound in this case. This is a very standard reaction, and it is surprising that a book messed this one up. I strongly suggest you change the book/material you're studying from.

Comment: May I ask, however which book this came from?

Comment: @C_Lycoris It's not from any standard organic chemistry book. The book is called "Problems in Organic Chemistry", and is basically a chapter-wise question bank for the JEE exam.

Comment: Referring to the product through its Fischer structure alone was an obvious red flag. Ditch this textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxidation  of alkene to 1,2-*syn*-diol by cold basic $\ce{KMnO4}$ is a common classification test for alkene in undergraduate organic chemistry laboratory courses. OP had correctly recognized that this reaction is a case of *syn*-dihydroxylation, and OP's conclusion of the product to be *meso* is also correct since the alkene in hand is a *cis*-but-2-ene. The schematic representation of the proposed mechanism is given below:

[image: Mechanism for oxidation by KMnO41]
[Source of the scheme](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/syn-dihydroxylation-alkenes-kmno4-oso4/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20alkenes%20into%20cis,Osmium%20tetroxide%20(OsO4)%3A&text=Since%20it%20is%20a%20strong,it%20further%20to%20a%20carbonyl.)

Since but-2-ene structure is planer and a prochiral molecule, it has two faces (*Si*- or *Re*-face; above or below the plane) to get attacked by a reactant, here it is $\ce{KMnO4}$. The above mechanism displays the attack by only one face. The oxidation gives butan-2,3-diol by syn-attack on that face. The product has two stereocenters and the stereochemistry of that product is $(2R,3S)$. As indicated in the diagram, the product also has a plane of symmetry, and hence, the $\ce{C}$2 stereocenter is the mirror image of the $\ce{C}$3 stereocenter. Therefore, the product is a *meso*-compound.

If the $\ce{KMnO4}$ attack is done on the opposite plane, the product would be $(2S,3R)$-butan-2,3-diol, if numbering has maintained the same. This is essentially the same *meso*-product, as we discussed above.

If the starting substrate is *trans*-but-2-ene, the $\ce{KMnO4}$ attack from one face gives you $(2S,3S)$-butan-2,3-diol, while the $\ce{KMnO4}$ attack from opposite face gives you $(2R,3R)$-butan-2,3-diol. Since possibility of attacking from the *Si*-fase and/or *Re*-face is $0.5$ (or $50\%$), you get essentially a racemic mixture.

Based on above facts, OP's textbook description of the reaction is erroneous, not only on stereochemistry, but also on the notation of the reaction (it is *syn*- not *sym*-addition).